# DbContext state and global query filters

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I've defined a global query filter in my OnModelCreating as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasQueryFilter(e => e.UserId == _currentUser || _currentUserIsAdmin);
```

And added the following method to my DbContext:

```
private int? _currentUser;
private bool _currentUserIsAdmin;
public void SetCurrentUser (int? currentUser)
{
  _currentUser = currentUser;
  _currentUserIsAdmin = Users.Find(currentUser)?.Role == "Admin";
}
```

However, I realized that when resolving my DbContext from the container it always resolves the very same instance. That means that two concurrent API calls would both call SetCurrentUser and overwrite it for the other API call - oops.

How to perform this properly?

My DI code looks like this:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
using var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
[...]
var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
```

Comment: _"when resolving my DbContext from the container it always resolves the very same instance"_ - that should definitely not happen. If so, you've done your DI wrong. Show your DI.

Comment: I've added my console application's DI structure to the original question.

Comment: That does not return the same DbContext instance for two requests. Why do you think so?

Comment: I've added a readonly field "Guid instanceId" to my DbContext and set it to Guid.NewGuid() in the DbContext's ctor. Regardless of how often I call GetRequiredService, the returned DbContext has the same InstanceId. Also if I dispose the DbContext, the next call to a "different" DbContext obtained with GetRequiredService fails because the DbContext is already disposed.

Comment: You should not be calling GetRequiredService anyway, but that call is scoped by default. If you call it twice in one scope, it'll give you the same context twice. Please read [ask] and provide all relevant details in your code.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that pointed me into the right direction. Of course I need to create new scopes, thanks!